# SAP GUI Scripting: new session from VBA

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am searching for macro script that opens new session when current session is running.

Problem is that macro opens new session when it's only opened, but not makes new session when current session is running example transaction after pressing execute button.

My macro below:

```
Private Sub nextSession()

Dim nSessions As Integer

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

Set sapCon = SAPApp.Children(0)

Set session = sapCon.Children(0)

nSessions = sapCon.Sessions.Count

session.CreateSession

Do

    Application.Wait (Now() + 500 * ms)

    If sapCon.Sessions.Count > nSessions Then Exit Do

Loop

Set sapSession = sapCon.Sessions.Item(CInt(sapCon.Sessions.Count - 1))

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how this question relates to [\[sapui5\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sapui5/info)?

Comment: I thought about SapGui sorry

Comment: I think that SAP GUI Scripting cannot execute in parallel sessions, even when there is one session "Busy" after user action.

Comment: I noticed that VBA script is running when I have one session only opened and other session is running Sript is not running when all session are running

Comment: To open new session when current session is running I use from sap menu new sap gui window So when such action is possible by hand I thing is also possible using VBA